# Looking for a lossless compression api similar to smushit

Tags: optimization, image-processing

Anyone know of an lossless image compression api/service similar to smushit from yahoo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From their own [FAQ](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/smushit/faq.html#faq_crushtool):

> **WHAT TOOLS DOES** *SMUSH.IT* **USE TO SMUSH IMAGES?**
>
> We have found many good tools for reducing image size. Often times these tools are specific to particular image formats and work much better in certain circumstances than others. To "smush" really means to try many different image reduction algorithms and figure out which one gives the best result.
>
> These are the algorithms currently in use:
>
> 1. [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php): to identify the image type and to convert GIF files to PNG files.
> 2. [pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/): to strip unneeded chunks from PNGs. We are also experimenting with other PNG reduction tools such as [pngout](http://advsys.net/ken/util/pngout.htm), [optipng](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/), [pngrewrite](http://entropymine.com/jason/pngrewrite/). Hopefully these tools will provide improved optimization of PNG files.
> 3. [jpegtran](http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/jpegtran/): to strip all metadata from JPEGs (currently disabled) and try progressive JPEGs.
> 4. [gifsicle](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/): to optimize GIF animations by stripping repeating pixels in different frames.
>
> More information about the smushing process is available at the [Optimize Images](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#opt_images) section of Best Practices for High Performance Web pages.

It mentions several good tools. By the way, the very same FAQ mentions that Yahoo will make *Smush.It* a [public API](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/smushit/faq.html#faq_api) sooner or later so that you can run at it your own. Until then you can just upload images separately for *Smush.It* [here](http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/).

Comment: Nearly two years later, and there is still no API.

Answer (score 5):

Try Kraken Image Optimizer: https://kraken.io/signup

The developer's plan is free - but only returns dummy results. You must subscribe to one of the paid plans to use the API, however, the [Web Interface](https://kraken.io/web-interface) is free and unlimited for images of up to 1MB.

Find out more in the [Kraken documentation](https://kraken.io/docs).

Answer (score 2):

See this:

http://github.com/thebeansgroup/smush.py

It's a Python implementation of smushit that can be run off-line to optimise your images without uploading them to Yahoo's service.

Answer (score 1):

**As I know the best image compression for me is : [Tinypng](https://tinypng.com/)**

They have also API : https://tinypng.com/developers

> Once you retrieve your key, you can immediately start shrinking
> images. Official client libraries are available for Ruby, PHP,
> Node.js, Python and Java. You can also use the WordPress plugin, the
> Magento 1 extension or improved Magento 2 extension to compress your
> JPEG and PNG images.

And **First 500 images per month is for free**

**Tip :** Via using their **API**, you have **no limit about file-size** *(not max 5MB each as their online tool)*